# so I have this list which contains variables in it I want to print the variable name and not its value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, variables

```
objects = [ALI_ELDIYAB,BILAL_HASSAN,DANIA_RAHMANI,DANIEL_AIGBE,HAMD_ALFARES,KHALED_AL_SHAIBANI,LINA_ISSA,LUMA_ABDELAZIZ,MARIAM_BASHER,MOHAMMED_BINDAGHER,NADAY_ALHAMMALI,NISRIIN_ABDI,OMAR_HAFEZ,OMAR_SLEIMAN,OMAR_MOUSTAFA,RAHAF_IBRAHIM,RASIL_ALSAKKA,SETYA_GHAHREMANI,SHARMAAKE_HANDBO,YAHYA_ABDELBAGI,YOUSIF_KASHWAN] = ["80.80%"
```

,"78%","71.20%"
,"78%","72%","74%","70%","78%","44%","74.80%","77.60%","67.60%","66.80%","83.20%","77.60%","68.80%","82%","82%"
,"59.20%","64%","76.40%"]

Comment: Question doesn't have proper information about question. Try to give more information.

Comment: Better use a dictionary with variable names as keys. Then you can easily print these keys.

Comment: You can't put variables into a list, only values (which might be specified as variables, literals or any other expression - but only the resulting values will end up in the list, not the expressions themselves.)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that maps keys to values:

```
data = {
    "ALI_ELDIYAB": "80.80%",
    "BILAL_HASSAN": "78%",
    "DANIA_RAHMANI": "71.20%",
    "DANIEL_AIGBE": "78%",
    "HAMD_ALFARES": "72%",
    "KHALED_AL_SHAIBANI": "74%",
    "LINA_ISSA": "70%",
    "LUMA_ABDELAZIZ": "78%",
    "MARIAM_BASHER": "44%",
    "MOHAMMED_BINDAGHER": "74.80%",
    "NADAY_ALHAMMALI": "77.60%",
    "NISRIIN_ABDI": "67.60%",
    "OMAR_HAFEZ": "66.80%",
    "OMAR_SLEIMAN": "83.20%",
    "OMAR_MOUSTAFA": "77.60%",
    "RAHAF_IBRAHIM": "68.80%",
    "RASIL_ALSAKKA": "82%",
    "SETYA_GHAHREMANI": "82%",
    "SHARMAAKE_HANDBO": "59.20%",
    "YAHYA_ABDELBAGI": "64%",
    "YOUSIF_KASHWAN": "76.40%",
}
```

Then, you can use e.g. `for name, score in data.items()` to iterate over the pairs.

Comment: what if I wanna do something lik  for i in data:
    if i < "70%":
        results =' good '
        print(results)

Comment: Then you just do that. Though you should probably keep the percentages as numbers instead of strings for easier comparison; you can always print them with percent signs...

Comment: I tried to print but nothing appeard

Comment: for i in objects.values():
    if objects.values() < '70':
        print(i) does this make sense ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. :) You might want to ask a new question with your current code.